# Windows phone 8.1 button click event not working

Tags: windows-phone-8, buttonclick

The click option from 
doesn't create click events, I even tried with MouseLeftButton
but nothing reacts. I will attach my "xaml" file to see what is 
wrong with it. The only solution is to place the  object 
after the splash screen code, and set visibility to true after splash
screen ends. I am asking for a better solution to place my  object 
in the  and to react at Click events.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" xmlns:ec="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
xmlns:sysctrl="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
x:Class="SplashScreen.MainPage"
mc:Ignorable="d"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=Main}">

<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <ec:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding DataLoaded}" 
                          Value="False" 
                          TrueState="Loading"
                          FalseState="Loaded"/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>



<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="DataStates">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:2" To="Loaded">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Loading">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" 
                                                   Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPanel">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Loaded">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" 
                                     To="0" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" 
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="stackPanel" 
                                     d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" 
          Grid.Row="1" 
          Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="67*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="85*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <phone:Pivot  Margin="0,10,0,-160" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

            <phone:PivotItem Header="Settings" >
                <StackPanel Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            >
                    <TextBox Name="PrintText"
                         Width="300"
                         Height="196" Margin="66,10,66,274"/>
                    <Button  Click="Button_Click"

                             IsHitTestVisible="True"
                             IsEnabled="True"
                        Width="100"
                        Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.34,-2"
                        Margin="166,0"
                        >
                        <Image Source="upload.png" 
                            Stretch="Fill" 
                            Width="50"
                            Height="50"
                            />
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="View Statistics">
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="Notification">
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>

    </Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0.552"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>     
        <Image Source="screen_loader.png"
            Width="350"
            Height="350" Margin="65,120"/>
        <ProgressBar Height="10" Margin="0,20,0,0" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Click event for which property?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I solved it. The problem was that the object "stackPanel" was in front of the main screen so the touch events weren't handled in my <Button Click="Button_Click"> method.
The solution was to set the GridPanel a property Loaded="ContentPanel_GotFocus" which was triggered when was focused.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of an XY problem. I think what you want to do is detect Tap events, raised when the user taps over the button. Just change the event it's handling to Tap.